# Configure AWS toolkit for Visual Studio code

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

Trying to install and configure AWS toolkit to Visual Studio Code.
Command `Command palette->Create Credentials profile` brings two files :

```
credentials file content

[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

config file content

[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = text
```

Choose `Command palette->AWS profile profile:default` generates error:

```
2022-02-03 10:03:51 [ERROR]: log level: info
2022-02-03 10:03:52 [INFO]: Retrieving AWS endpoint data
2022-02-03 10:03:52 [INFO]: OS:  Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
2022-02-03 10:03:52 [INFO]: Visual Studio Code Extension Host Version:  1.63.2
2022-02-03 10:03:52 [INFO]: AWS Toolkit Version:  1.35.0
2022-02-03 10:03:52 [INFO]: telemetry cache not found: 'c:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode\telemetryCache'
2022-02-03 10:04:18 [ERROR]: Error getting AccountId: [InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    at constructor.h (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:5:9005)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:21079)
    at constructor.emit (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:20788)
    at constructor.emitEvent (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:6641)
    at constructor.e (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:2227)
    at U.runTo (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:18:1767)
    at c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:18:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:2438)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:6696)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:21183)
    at constructor.emit (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:20788)
    at constructor.emitEvent (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:6641)
    at constructor.e (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:2227)
    at U.runTo (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:18:1767)
    at c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:18:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:2438)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:6696)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:21183)
    at e (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:6:20964)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\g\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.35.0\dist\extension.js:1:209012)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)] {
  code: 'InvalidClientTokenId',
  time: 2022-02-03T08:04:18.158Z,
  requestId: '00c18899-6f97-40c1-9788-b2156b350ebb',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 83.95345343935642
}
2022-02-03 10:04:18 [ERROR]: login: failed to connect with "profile:default": Could not determine Account Id for credentials
```

How to connect AWS toolkit to my VSCode?

Comment: Getting the same error - if you do find the solution, pls share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the access and secret key from AWS and insert them in place of the `XXXXXXX` placeholders.

You can get this information in the AWS Cloud -> IAM -> Access Management -> Users -> Select your user -> Security credentials -> Access Keys

You will find here the Access Key ID, but the Secret Key is only shown once when you are creating this item. You maybe have it stored somewhere, or you can create another Access Key pair and use that.

I have done this and I can connect to AWS Toolkit fine.

[AWS Toolkit Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx0Ej.png)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I tried to make it work:

1. Ensure that the credentials file is in C:\Users\UserName\ .aws\ {credentials}
2. Was prompted that default region for this profile was xxx. Changed it accordingly.
3. Restarted the VS code(yeah, I know) :D
4. Chose the profile and it opened okay.